# What's the default color for the background of a SwiftUI List?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I know how to change the background color of a SwiftUI Views list, but I cannot find the default color. I've tried using the MacOS 'Digital Color Meter', but it just doesn't pick it up right.

As you can see in this image, I've tried to set the background color of a list row (using `.listRowBackground` to the exact same of the surrounding list based off of the values from Digital Color Meter.

Does anyone actually know what the default background color actually is?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you got RGB values wrong? Maybe you have used an external screen with different Color Space? Please check my answer for the correct values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** it looks like it is UIColor.secondarySystemBackground

**Long answer:**

I have tried **Digital Color Meter** app the sam as you did. It shows this RGB values: 242, 242, 247.

I have created such color:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    public static let ListBGColor = Color("ListBGColor")
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
                ForEach(0..<5) {_ in
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                        .padding()
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.ListBGColor)
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Result: the same color as the background (testes on Simulator and iPhone):
[image]

Answer (score 9):

After doing some testing, it looks like it might be `UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground`.

## Examples

### Default

[image: Without setting secondary system color]

### With UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground

I'm using it to set the list row background:
`.listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground))`

[image: Using the secondary system color]

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about `List{ }`, it is `.systemGroupedBackground`. Check in dark mode: `.systemSecondaryBackground` does something different.

Answer (score 0):

The default color is different for each ListStyle and platform and I don't think SwiftUI exposes these colors. You could technically [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) the list view and get it's background color through UIKit.