# Apply color to list row background conditionally

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

One can use `.listRowBackground` to change the color of a list row in `SwiftUI`.
I am trying to use this to color the background of a row *conditionally*.

What's the correct color to *persist* the system's default background color for a row where the condition does *not* apply?
`Color.clear` is wrong, cause it really clears the background instead of falling back to the default. `Color.white` also is wrong, because it is not agnostic to dark mode...

So, what's the system agnostic default background color of a list in SwiftUI?

##### TL;DR:

Consider the following (Playground) code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Item: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var completed: Bool
}

struct ListView: View {
  let items = [
    Item(completed: true),
    Item(completed: false),
    Item(completed: false),
    Item(completed: false),
    Item(completed: true),
  ]
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(items) { item in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(item.id.uuidString)
        }
        .listRowBackground(item.completed ? Color.green : Color.clear)
      }
    }
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ListView())
```

The preview looks like this (and please be aware the background of the rows is cleared out):
[image]

If I **comment out** `.listRowBackground(item.completed ? Color.green : Color.clear)`, the preview is this:

[image]

##### Even more TL;DR

I can help myself with the workaround of introducing a conditional view modifier:

```swift
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition() {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

I can then apply this with

```swift
        .if(item.completed) { view in
          view
            .listRowBackground(Color.green)
        }
```

This *does* result in the desired view–but is a bit gnarly. There must be a better way I would hope...

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the default color for the background of a SwiftUI List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65195464/whats-the-default-color-for-the-background-of-a-swiftui-list)

Comment: No, I am afraid it does not–there isn't a really good answer given there (and my workaround with the `if` modifier is imho better than any answer for that question). But I might have found an even better solution: `.listRowBackground(item.completed ? Color.green : .none)` seems to work exactly how I want it to work, I found out in the meantime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution–by simply trying out `.none` for the false branch of the ternary expression:

```swift
.listRowBackground(item.completed ? Color.green : .none)
```

does exactly what I want. Amazes me that I couldn't find any mention on this neither in the documentation nor anywhere else…

Comment: Wow!   Amazed that's not more common knowledge.  However `.none` is normally the `nil` case of an optional value.  So does that mean this takes a `View?` or does `some View` also include a nil view?

Comment: so I did the obvious and looked at the signature: `func listRowBackground<V>(_ view: V?) -> some View where V : View` so yes, it takes an optional, and an optional view satisfies `some View`.

Comment: Yeah, I was amazed as well that I did not find a single mention anywhere...